# Link to iTunes music

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, itunes

I would like to enable users to as simply as possible go to a certain music album in the iTunes music store (not the app store). Is it possible to create such a direct link that opens iTunes music store with particular music album or song? You can see such behavior in Shazam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/itmsLinkMaker

Comment: In case that ever breaks, here's the front-door URL (which currently redirects to that one): http://apple.com/itunes/linkmaker/

Comment: What's the best way to access linkmaker procedurally?  Now it is an AJAX page that populates the html when you click Search.